# How to convert any string to valid CSV field?

Tags: c#, csv

I need to save table to CSV file. Each cell of table could contains strings with characters like: " , ; ' and new lines.
How to convert those strings to valid CSV fields that could be opened in Excel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
csvCell = "\"" + cell.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
```

This wraps the cell text in "double quotes" and escapes "double quotes" inside the cell with double "double quotes".

Comment: I'm not familiar with `c` but I'm sure you are wrong, because you escape only double quotes. By csv specs, you should escape line feed and carriage return. see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but here is my solution as an extension method on the object class:

```
public static class ObjectUtil {

    public static string ToCsvString(this object obj) {
        string result = obj.ToString();
        if (result.Contains("\"")) {
            result = result.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
        }
        if (result.Contains(",")) {
            result = string.Format("\"{0}\"", result);
        }
        if (result.Contains(Environment.NewLine)) {
            result = string.Format("\"{0}\"", result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The contains on "," & "\n" should be merged to ``result.Contains(',') || result.Contains('\n') || result.Contains('\r')`` as currently you'll wrap the value in quotes twice if it contains both a newline & a comma

Answer (score 2):

Wrap each cell/value with double quotes or use tab as delimiter \t.

You need to watch our for doube quotes in cell/value, you can replace them with single quotes or use escape char.

Eaxmple:

```
"Test", "test,123", "test 123", "test
123", "test 345"
"Test", "test,123", "test 123", "test
123", "test 345"
"Test", "test,123", "test 123", "test
123", "test 345"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [formal CSV spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) for further guidance as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a string extension to handle this simply

```
public static string Escape(this string value)
{
    return string.Format("\"{0}\"", (value ?? string.Empty).Replace("\"", "\"\""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace carriage returns with spaces, and then wrap each text value with double quotes.

I havent tried using tab separated files, but one could use that to remove any ambiguity with characters?